# Changing Xbox settings from Adult to child or teen

Tags: xbox-360

My son set up the Xbox accounts and put me as a child and himself as an adult. Is there a way I can change that?

Answer (score 2):

Ok so you need to goto [Xbox.com](http://www.xbox.com)

go to the account page[image]

at the upper right corner there should be a button called "Sign In" click this and sign into your xbox live account,

Under settings and preferences, click privacy and online settings.

To change anything related to the childs account you MUST have the parent account in order to make the changes.

This can also be done via the console itself.

Go to the settings tab on the console and select privacy and online settings,

Within this menu should be the ability to change it but again you must be signed in as the adult account.

Comment: That's only for privacy settings; it may not answer what is being asked.

Comment: You change privilage settings in this section

Answer (score 2):

We had the SAME issue - teen created account and made himself an adult. When I went to put on restrictions, couldn't until the account got changed to child. Contacted MS, and here is what we did:

1. Log in to Account.Microsoft.Com using the email address for the adult account
2. Select family
3. Under Family, select View your Family
4. select leave family
5. Sign out from the adult account
6. Sign in using the parent account
7. go back to family
8. select add family member
9. then select as a child
10. please follow the same process upon converting another account to a child.

For further inquiries, please check our support website which is https://support.xbox.com/en-US/my-account/microsoft-account/update-microsoft-account-country-region

It WORKED!!! Now he can keep all he's earned, but we have some time limits in place. And so far, we don't think he has figured out a work around. Maybe he will... seems like they often do... but for now, it's working

Comment: This answer saved me and deserves more attention!