# Add adult account and Xbox One to existing Microsoft Family Account as a child

Tags: xbox-one

My sincerest apologies if this feels like a duplication, but I want to make sure I have an answer to my exact question so I don't do something irreversible. I have already reviewed this question's answer, technically, it's answer number two. [Changing Xbox settings from Adult to child or teen](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/177748/changing-xbox-settings-from-adult-to-child-or-teen)

I've got three Microsoft Accounts: Call them Parent 1, Parent 2 and Kid.

Parent 1's Microsoft account has been used to setup a family and the Kid and the Kid's computer have been added to the family. Associated permissions and access control have been applied as expected.

Parent 2's Microsoft account and subscriptions have been used on an Xbox One by Parent 2 and, unfortunately, more often than not Kid. The Kid's account has never been used on the Xbox.

Here are the goals:

A. Add the Parent 2 account and hopefully, by extension, the Xbox to the Family account setup by Parent 1.

B. Not lose the xbox game history/progress achieved by Kid on Parent 2's account.

C. Parent 1 controls access to content/features/duration/etc. on the Xbox and Parent 2's account and they cannot be overridden by Kid logged into the Xbox as Parent 2.

It seems like I can simply invite the Parent 2 account as Member to the family setup by Parent 1 per the instructions in the link above. Can I achieve all three goals? Thank you very much!